# Cannot convert value of type '[RKDataStreamingMask]' to expected argument type 'RKDataStreamingMask'

Tags: xcode, swift

Xcode 7 and my code:

```
func sendSetDataStreamingCommand {
let mask = RKDataStreamingMask.AccelerometerFilteredAll |
RKDataStreamingMask.IMUAnglesFilteredAll |
RKDataStreamingMask.QuaternionAll ;
self.robot.enableSensors(mask,atStreamingRate:RKStreamingRate.DataStreamingRate10);
}
```

the warning is :

```
swift Binary operator '|' cannot be applied to two UIViewAutoresizing operands
```

then change code:

```
func sendSetDataStreamingCommand {
let mask=[RKDataStreamingMask.AccelerometerFilteredAll,
RKDataStreamingMask.IMUAnglesFilteredAll,
RKDataStreamingMask.QuaternionAll]
self.robot.enableSensors(mask,atStreamingRate:RKStreamingRate.DataStreamingRate10);
}
```

then warning in last sentence is :

```
Cannot convert value of type '[RKDataStreamingMask]' to expected argument type 'RKDataStreamingMask'
```

Please teach me how to do ?Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To declare a variable containing multiple members of `OptionSetType` you have to annotate the type explicitly, otherwise the square brackets are treated as an array.

```
let mask : RKDataStreamingMask = [.AccelerometerFilteredAll, .IMUAnglesFilteredAll, .QuaternionAll]
```